# couchDB pouchDB sync - angular-pouchdb - Type Error

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to get sync() working between pouchDB and a local couchDB, within an Angular app (using angular-pouchdb).

```
  this.system =  pouchDB('system');
  var remoteSystem =  pouchDB('http://localhost:5984/system');

  this.system.sync(remoteSystem, {live : true}).on('change', function (change) {
    // yo, something changed!
    console.log('changed');
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    // yo, we got an error!
    console.log('error');
  });
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (angular.js:4146)
```

If I remove the .on chains the error goes away (but the sync still doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `angular-pouchdb`, then the `pouchdb` object is not really a `PouchDB` object; it's a special `angular-pouchdb` thing.

Luckily, the `sync` and `replicate` APIs are also available on the databases themselves. So you can do:

```
local.sync(remote, { live: true})
```

and it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of PouchDB has the sync method on the PouchDB object.

```
var remote = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/system');
var local = new PouchDB('system');

PouchDB.sync(local, remote, { live: true })
  .on('change', function (info) {
    // handle change
  }).on('complete', function (info) {
    // handle complete
  }).on('uptodate', function (info) {
    // handle up-to-date
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    // handle error
  });
```